# What is this -- seems to be bike-related?

Tags: parts, accessories

I'd love to know what it is that is pictured below:

[image: Detail shot from car driver's seat]
[image: Detail shot from kitchen table]

It is worth driving 320 km to pick it up. (Makes no sense.)

I am trying to win a bet that I can find out what it is.

Comment: Seems like a silly bet if the part number is visible in the pictures.

Comment: Not sure why the items in question are wrapped in plastic?

Comment: @StephenTouset TAQ-33 means nothing to a nonbiker. And there are Zillions of parts referred to as TAQ-33.

Comment: Wrapped since it was a quick shot, and to make it harder I guess.

Comment: @Downvoter Thanks for downvoting this first question of mine, yielding my reps below 101. What kind of community is this?

Comment: @TheBlastOne: While I'm not the one who downvoted you, this question does not meet our quality standard here. The photos don't actually show the part, what the part is can be discovered with a 2 minute google search, if it isn't obvious already, and there is no problem to be solved. Voting down a question is a method of teaching what is acceptable and useful here. Attacking someone for down voting is not acceptable. If there is a serious pattern of harassment, and then is best referred to a moderator.

Comment: Oh I know about the voting system, I just was a bit concerned about getting below the starting 100 rep points for seemingly nothing. I had a question, it was answered, and I am fine with that. Attack would look different, no? If I have to live with < 100 for nothing, you can easly live with me being not happy with it, can't you?

Comment: @zenbike >>what the part is can be discovered with a 2 minute google search, if it isn't obvious already, and there is no problem to be solved. << that´s what you say. I was not able to identify it, so either it isn't *that* obvious, or I am too much of a non-expert (which I am, which made me ask). Yes there was no real "problem" to be solved, just a question to be answered. There are lots of no-problem-to-be-solved-questions around here that arise from pure interest instead. So what's the problem? (I'm not asking to annoy, but to hear your opinion.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like an adjustable quill stem.

http://www.amazon.co.uk/TAQ-33-ADJUSTABLE-ALUMINUM-STEM-ST3/dp/B001DGGVQ2

oh, and not worth driving that far to get one.

Comment: You beat me to the answer by seconds.

Comment: You've got it!  The bottom shot is the bottom end of the stem -- you can see the angle of the wedge through the plastic cover.

Comment: Cool. Thanks a lot. Will accept if it turns out to be correct. On Thursday...

Comment: I now just hope there was more than that on the shopping list so the distance was worth it somehow :O